# How to add addEventListener to from parent to child in pure Javasvript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ecmascript-6, frontend

i need your help. My code structure is like this:

```
<div class="header">
  <p>Button</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Option 1</>
    <li>Option 2</>
    <li>Option 3</>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i want to use addEventListener here on p tag, on clicking it we need to hide and show ul.
This is one of my friends challenge question, please anyone help me how to achieve this.  p tag is inside header class. I cannot change the format, need to impliment like this. I want to use pure javascrript for this problem

[Codepen Link:](https://codepen.io/underratedslay2/pen/zYEdVWy)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and please also note that stack overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: i am quite new to this.. can you please help[

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the DOM through the selector, add click events, switch variables

```js
const header = document.querySelector('.header')
const btn = header.querySelector('p')
const ul = header.querySelector('ul')
let isShow = false
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  isShow = !isShow
  ul.style.display = isShow ? 'none' : 'block'
})
```

```html
<div class="header"> <p>Button</p> <ul> <li>Option 1</> <li>Option 2</> <li>Option 3</> </ul> </div>
```

Comment: Bonus: Beside using Javascript, you can also use ```details``` and ```summary``` tag to toggle text.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add it to multiple elements

```js
const toggleVisibilityOfEl = (el) => el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == 'hidden' ? 'visible' : 'hidden')

// in case you add classes you can add the path to the element/ element here
const allPElements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
const allUlElements = document.querySelectorAll('ul')

 allPElements.forEach(e =>
    e.addEventListener('click', (event) =>
      allUlElements.forEach(toggleVisibilityOfEl)
    )
  )
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <p>Button</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Option 1</li>
    <li>Option 2</li>
    <li>Option 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If you clone the html multiple times then you will hide all ul by 1 button, and I don't think that will be intended.,

Comment: I guess it not going to be a full Project. I would never recommend using any Tag as selector only classes or preferably Ids. So I guess in this use case its fine to do it like this as well. But you are right of cause, this can definitely lead to unexpected behaviour.